# Using Chello to create a card on Trello

Tags: c#, .net, trello

I'm trying to create card on Trello Board using Chello and I get no results.

I can see that my code connects if I try

```
var chello = new ChelloClient("<my API key>");
var b = chello.Members.AllBoards("<my user name>");
```

In this case `b` will have my boards returned.

but this fails

```
        var c = new Card();
        c.Name = "Test2";
        c.IdBoard = "Test";
        c.IdList = "Done";
        chello.Cards.Create(c);
        chello.Cards.Update(c);
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: You could try Trello.NET instead (https://github.com/dillenmeister/Trello.NET/wiki) and see if that works better.

Comment: Trello.NET works perfectly. I'm happy using it instead of Chello :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that `c.IdBoard` should not be set to the NAME of the board, but to the ID. When viewing a board you can find the ID in the address bar, for example `https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c`.

In this case, `4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c` is the ID.

The same goes for `c.IdList`.